# Is there any way to switch the default scripting language in Google spreadsheets from the Excel one to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets

I would like to know whether you can use Javascript as the default cell language in Google spreadsheets rather than all the functions that have been mapped from Excel.

The excel functions make me so unhappy I want to chew my fist off. Using `=concatenate(a2, b2)` rather than `=a1 + b2` or equality calculations that require crazy `if` statements. Is there away to switch a setting so that you can just write Javascript directly into the cells instead?

(NB I don't want to use another spreadsheet since I need a need a number of the Google SS integrations).

Also... this is not a dig at Google - their SSs are excellent. I just hate the language they were forced to support.

Comment: Not an answer, but `=CONCATENATE(A2,B2)` == `=A2&B2` (in a spreadsheet formula).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can switch the scripting language but you *can* create custom JavaScript functions within the spreadsheet.

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions